# No endpoints specified (Parameter 'configuration')

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis

i'm connecting to redis server. i'm standing up the application from port 6379. i am creating my redis service class.

```
public class RedisService
{
    private readonly string _redisHost;

    private readonly string _redisPort;

    private ConnectionMultiplexer _redis;
    public IDatabase db { get; set; }

    public RedisService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _redisHost = configuration["Redis:Host"];

        _redisPort = configuration["Redis:Port"];
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        var configString = $"{_redisHost}:{_redisPort}";

        _redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configString);
    }

    public IDatabase GetDb(int db)
    {
        return _redis.GetDatabase(db);
    }
}
```

I have made my definitions in the JSON section of the appsettings.json

```
"Redis": {
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Post": 6379 
},
```

I've done the Configure service part on the startup side. and I also added it as middleware in the Configure section.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<RedisService>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

the error I received is as follows

> No endpoints specified (Parameter 'configuration')

```
_redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configString);
```

Comment: In your app settings - is this a typo? "Post": 6379? (The 's').

Comment: yess: ) okey sorry i found a typo and i fixed the error thank you

Comment: appsettings.json in this here